Need advice for well water chlorine
I have a filtering system for my well since the water is high on sulfur (smell a lot). The system has chlorine that ‘’should’’ inject in the system.
The thing is that the nozzle gets clogged after few days and it seems to be mounted upside down, what I mean by upside down is that the injector line comes from under the main pipe and injects in that pipe from the bottom. The nozzle gets clogged in my opinion because of the stagnant water at the bottom of the pipe. My question is, basicly if I could mount that injector on the top of that pipe so it injects down, instead of injecting from below, would it fix my injector that clogs after few days? Thanks for your answer!

With advice and direction from the local supply house, I installed our injection system. The instructions state explicitly to have the injector on top. I get three months between injector valve changes before the iron in the water reacts at the nozzle valve, but it's better than the few days you experience.

Thank you for your comment, will try to mount it on top

I've had a chloreine injection system on our well water for 15+ years now, and the people that installed it put the injection point coming in from above.  So likely you have the same sort of setup and I can't imagine any reason it has to be from underneath.  Granted, ours was in a location that installing it from the top made the most sense, but certainly I'd think that there shouldn't be any issues injecting from above.
Whether changing the injection point from below to above will reduce/eliminate your clogging, I can't answer that.  We have our injection point replaced every year, and I think over the 15+ years, it's clogged once, and one time got stuck open so water was slowly backfeeding into our bleach bin.  But overall it's been quite reliable.
Can you visibly see it's clogged when you replace the old one?  Wondering if you can tell what is clogging it, and

Thank you very much for those infos, I’ll try to mount it on the top and change the injector since it just been ‘’serviced’’ not replaced. Thanks again
